# Caching Common Table Expressions (CTE) queries in NHibernate

Tags: sql-server, nhibernate, caching, common-table-expression

I have a table holding hierarchical data that I am querying for from my web app using NHibernate. It's pretty straight forward

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Relationships](
    [RelationshipId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [ParentId] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [ParentTypeId] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [ChildId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [ChildTypeId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL
)
```

Now to query information from this table I'm using a feature of SQL Server (since 2005) called Common Table Expressions, or CTE for short. It lets me write recursive queries which are extremely useful for table like the one above.

```
WITH Ancestors(RelationshipId, ParentId, ChildId) 
AS 
(
    SELECT r.RelationshipId, r.ParentId, r.ChildId 
        FROM Relationships r 
        WHERE ChildId = :objectId 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT r.RelationshipId, r.ParentId, r.ChildId 
        FROM Relationships r 
            INNER JOIN Ancestors 
                ON Ancestors.ParentId = r.ChildId 
) 
SELECT RelationshipId, ParentId, ChildId FROM Ancestors
```

Now, this is great and the performance isn't that bad but it can be taxing when I try to use this to determine ancestors going up the tree, or worse, using a similar query to determine decendants.

Now I'd like to simply cache the results from this query but I'm getting an error from nHibernate `Index was outside the bounds of the array.` if I have `.SetCacheable(true)`. If I remove the cache support the query works fine.

The query works fine if I remove the caching support from my call to `Session.CreateSQLQuery()` Now I've looked online to try and find a cause but I haven't found a consensus amongst the results I found.

So while I am curios **why** it doesn't work, I'm more interested in finding a workaround to get caching to work with my CTE in nHibernate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up simply doing the following. I haven't tested the caching yet but I may have to sacrifices that in favor of the flexibility the CTE provides.

```
const string query = "WITH Ancestors(RelationshipId, ParentId, ChildId) " +
                        "AS " +
                        "( SELECT por.RelationshipId, por.ParentId, por.ChildId " +
                        "FROM PseudoObjectRelationships por WHERE ChildId = :objectId " +
                        "UNION ALL " +
                        "SELECT por.RelationshipId, por.ParentId, por.ChildId " +
                        "FROM PseudoObjectRelationships por " +
                        "INNER JOIN Ancestors " +
                        "ON Ancestors.ParentId = por.ChildId " +
                        ") " +
                        "SELECT RelationshipId, ParentId, ChildId FROM Ancestors";

return ((DynamicObjectRepository<TObject>)dynamicObjectRepository).CreateSQLQuery(query)
        .SetGuid("objectId", objectId)
        .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean<Relationship>())
        .List<Relationship>();
```

Answer (score 0):

I could do with seeing more detail for the error but I would say that you could use a named query instead...http://geekswithblogs.net/TStewartDev/archive/2010/04/11/caching-nhibernate-named-queries.aspx

Define your SQL in the XML (call a SP if you want) and then declare the Resultset. You are telling nhibernate what to expect back from the call so I think it can then work out how to cache it (guessing). I normally transform to a dto.

Be careful, you will need to clear the cache manually should the Db change. You aren't using entities so you have to clear the cache yourself if the underlying data is changed.